# After a while suddenly got index index out of range exception was unhandled

Tags: c#

After a while, the problem shows. I already debug it a lot of times and not found a solution. And I do not know much about C# and it is compulsory for my project. It keeps showing the problem and I really need a solution ASAP. I already search in here and try all the possible solution, but no luck. I mark the line that always show the problem,

```
int.TryParse(data2[0], out humidity);
int.TryParse(data2[1], out pH);
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int hr, min, sec;
        private int Daydate, monthdate, yeardate;
        private int i, humidity=0;
        private int j, pH=0;
        private int t = 0;
        private string data;
        // private string[] data2;
        private int flag;
        int[] data_new = new int[6];

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (comboBox1.Text == "" || comboBox2.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select Port/Baud Rate Settings");
                }
                else
                {
                    serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
                    serialPort1.DataReceived += SerialPort1_DataReceived; 
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    timer2.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized Access");
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t = 0;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
            Excel.Visible = true;          
            ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Humidity";
            ws.Cells[1, 2] = "pH";

            for(int j =2;j<= dataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1;j++)
            {
                for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[j, i] = dataGridView1.Rows[j-2].Cells[i-1].Value;
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(flag == 0)
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine("N");
                flag = 1;
            }
        }

        private void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
       //     if (t < 5)
         //   {
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();             
                    flag = 0; 
                    if(data != "")
                    {

                        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
                    }

                }              
              //  t++;
        //    }
        }

        private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Text = data;
            string[] data2 = new string[2];
            data2 = data.Split(new char[] { ',' });

            int.TryParse(data2[0], out humidity);
            int.TryParse(data2[1], out pH);

            // Array.Clear(data2, 0, data2.Length);

            textBox1.Text = humidity + "";
            textBox2.Text = pH + "";

            //if (Int32.Parse(data2[0]) > 0 && Int32.Parse(data2[1]) > 0)
            if (humidity > 0 && pH > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                //dataGridView1.Rows[i++].Cells[0].Value = Int32.Parse(data2[0]) + "";
                //dataGridView1.Rows[j++].Cells[1].Value = Int32.Parse(data2[1]) + "";
                dataGridView1.Rows[i++].Cells[0].Value = humidity + "";
                dataGridView1.Rows[j++].Cells[1].Value = pH + "";
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            timer2.Enabled = false; 
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Closed");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hr = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
            min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
            sec = DateTime.Now.Second;
            Daydate = DateTime.Now.Day;
            monthdate = DateTime.Now.Month;
            yeardate = DateTime.Now.Year;

            if (hr > 12)
                hr -= 12;

            label1.Text = hr + ":" + min + " ";
            label2.Text = Daydate + "/" + monthdate + "/" + yeardate;
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(today);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
            hr = DateTime.UtcNow.Hour;
            min = DateTime.UtcNow.Minute;
            sec = DateTime.UtcNow.Second;
            Daydate = DateTime.UtcNow.Day;           
            String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line/statement throws the error? Can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: It probably means that `data.Split()` didn't produce an array of 2 or more objects, indicating that `data` doesn't contain any `,`

Comment: What exception is thrown? Send the exception message...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, my serial communication actually giving more character than i wanted. so that data.split didnt produce array of 2. Thanks for the advice <3

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi its okay.. i think i found the SO that i want.. Thanks for your concern and ill ask if i still have any problem. Thanks.

Comment: @GrantWinney Im sorry im very new to this C# things. actually i already search and try for the solution that suggested in here, but failed. So that why im asking :( .. and yeah, String.split didnt produce 2 array.. and i tried the SO given below, and thanks that succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simple enough to see.

```
textBox3.Text = data; //Get input data, example "1,2", or "1" or "1,2,3"

string[] data2 = new string[2]; //Initialize to arra with 2 spots.
data2 = data.Split(new char[] { ',' });//Over write to array with unkown amount of spots

int.TryParse(data2[0], out humidity); //Parse first
int.TryParse(data2[1], out pH); //Parse second
```

I hoipe you see the issue by the comments, so how do we fix that?
The first thing we can do is to test the length and see that its approperiate.

```
textBox3.Text = data; //Get input data, example "1,2", or "1" or "1,2,3"

string[] data2 = data.Split(new char[] { ',' });
if(data2.length != 2){ 
    //Tell the user or something like the field needs to contain 2 numbers.
    return;
}
```

While where at it we might aswell take a look at another possible issue. TyParse returns a bool for a reason, it tells us if we succeeded or not. so we should have sometyhing like this aswell.

```
if(!int.TryParse(data2[0], out humidity)
   && !int.TryParse(data2[1], out pH)){
    //Tell the user or something like the field needs to contain 2 numbers.
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother, the data.split do not split to 2 array, and using both of the solution given, it okay now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **check** to **ensure** that your call to `.Split()` has *actually produced* two values - it might not, if the string doesn't contain a `,`.

So change your code to this :

```
data2 = data.Split(new char[] { ',' });

// CHECK to make sure you get **TWO VALUES** here! If not, return
if (data2.Length < 2)
{
    return;  // didn't split into two parts --> something's wrong
}

// only KNOW that you've CHECKED, convert the string parts into int
int.TryParse(data2[0], out humidity);
int.TryParse(data2[1], out pH);
```

Comment: Actually i do know the function of Return use for what.. Thank for that solution you provided.